# Div Wrapper Background color not displaying

Tags: html, css

My footer background color is not displaying...

What am I missing?

The test site is http://qtest.pw

*I am adding extra words as requested... Don't know what else to say.. So I will keep typing until it says its ok*

HTML

```
  <div id="FooterWrapper">  
    <div id="FooterDiv1"><img src="images/ada-logo.png" alt="American dental Association - Helmich Dental">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv2">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv3">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv4">
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#FooterWrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1232px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    background-color: #000;
}
#FooterDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv3 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv4 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Try researching **clearfix**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you add `min-height: 170px` your background color will display. Right now your footer doesn't have any height in the DOM so no color showing.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to clear the floats on the items contained with in;

```
#FooterWrapper:before,
#FooterWrapper:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

#FooterWrapper:after {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `#FooterWrapper` does not contain `float` properties but your child `div`s have a `float: left;` property assigned.

So, if you add the below properties to `#FooterWrapper` than you can get the background color as expected.

```
#FooterWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font: 100%/1.3 arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    background:#3F6A8A;

}
#FooterWrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1232px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
   

}
#FooterDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv3 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv4 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="FooterWrapper">  
    <div id="FooterDiv1"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/s9dbAfjlrks/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="American dental Association - Helmich Dental">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv2">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv3">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv4">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font: 100%/1.3 arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    background:#3F6A8A;

}
#FooterWrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1232px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    background-color:#000; 
}
#FooterDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv3 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
#FooterDiv4 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 19%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="FooterWrapper">  
    <div id="FooterDiv1"><img src="images/ada-logo.png" alt="American dental Association - Helmich Dental">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv2">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv3">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv4">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution.. Tell me if I am on the right track.. Or are there errors or bad code? It seems to work well

http://qtest.pw

Thanks to all that contributed!!!

HTML

```
  <div id="FooterWrapper">  
    <div id="FooterDiv1"><a href="http://www.mouthhealthy.org/en/" target="new"><img src="images/ada-logo.png" alt="American dental Association - Helmich Dental" class="imagecenter"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv2">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv3">
    </div>
    <div id="FooterDiv4">
  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
#FooterWrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1232px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    background-color: #000;
}
#FooterDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 1.6%;
    width: 23.4%;
    display: block;
}
#FooterDiv2 {
    clear: none;
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
}
#FooterDiv3 {
    clear: none;
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
}
#FooterDiv4 {
    clear: none;
    margin-right: 1.6%;
    width: 23.4%;
    display: block;
}
```